# img src with large image size on UIWebView taking time to load and sometimes crashes

Tags: iphone, html, image, uiwebview

I display html string on UIWebview, and html string comes from server.

In html which I retrieved from server, is having 10 images which are large sized with src attribute. those images total size is above 4 MB. when I load this html string into UIWebview, application takes 4 mins to load images sometimes and sometimes it crashes.

I want to know, if there is any solution to `<img src..>` tag where I can make thumbnail images.

Any response will greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Would you please attach the stack trace of the crash?

Comment: couldn't your server send smaller images?

Comment: on server side, url is stored, like BBCode... and from BBCode we are converting into HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find out on the server-side via java/html5 what browser your client is and what features it has. In doing so the server can determine the appropriate image size to send to the client.

My company has successfully implemented this with iPhone and Android client's retrieving images that are smaller in size as opposed to browser's on laptops receiving larger images.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Big chunks of memory allocated can trigger a sigkill 9 from springboard on heavy system load (by protection) even if you don't overlap the 46MB given for any single application running.

1. The best way to do this would be to load one image at a time.
2. For each individual image, create a smaller version.
3. Release the currently big image loaded since you have a smaller version of it.
4. Do it again for next, and so on.

You will reduce the impact of big loads.

The [Nimbus Framework](http://latest.docs.nimbuskit.info/group___nimbus_network_image.html) is doing image download and resize that way. Have a look.

For the UIWebview, I'm not sure of what you can do. Since you get the HTML before displaying it, you could perhaps grep the `<img>` tags and creating those thumbnails, storing them to the iPhone, replacing the `src` path of the original `<img>` tags by a local URL of your thumbs.

Comment: I cannot do these much of process, I am having UIWebview inside UITableView, and I show UIWebview to be displayed dynamically with height, so it should not scroll according to its content. If I do these much of process, it will be too slow to display HTML on web view.

Comment: I think you should take another approach to your problem. Using UIWebview in UITableView is at first frightening. What are you trying to achieve? I think there is another way to do it, solving your current problem.

Comment: I have one application in which I need to show forums/threads/posts and those posts can be in html on server side, I have API which gives me HTML code retaining all contents (i.e. position/location). I need to display all posts in list with the description (description is in HTML).

Comment: You should try to parse it yourself. Using web views will be very slow. Three20 do some HTML representation with inline images. (TTStyledTextLabel) http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_styled_text_label.php. It will be much more efficient.

Answer (score -2):

Probably the device you are using cannot support 4MB images when decompressed in a UIWebView.

Which device are you using?

4 minutes to load 4 images is a very long time. Is your network very bad? Otherwise it could be another indicator of wrong approach.

Being you I'll try to use native `UIImageView` to display the images and perform some kind of queued download, maybe with [ASIHTTP](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request).

So you can load and unload the images when you need them and avid keeping them always in memory.

As Jojas point, I still think that the answer is correct as the `UIWevView` [drains memory to render the DOM elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439728/uiwebview-size-limit).

Comment: I am loading html pages, and html pages have 10 <img> tags with src attributes,and in src attribute, the url comes for images are having very large images. so it takes time, there is nothing related to UIImageView, its about UIWebView. Please read question carefully.

Comment: Also, it is not only about images, I am getting other information along with images, so I cannot display images separately, html page should be displayed as it is designed.

Comment: I red the question carefully and I think that you are just requiring too much to your device with 10 **large** images in just one UIWebView, so I'm trying to suggest to change approach and just avoid using one crashing `UIWebView` and switch to multiple working `UIImageView`s.

Comment: As @JigneshBrahmkhatri answer issue, It's look like these question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439728/uiwebview-size-limit